# so_rcvtimeo default value in windows 8

Tags: windows, sockets, network-programming

I want to find the default value of so_rcvtimeo parameter related to socket timeout in Windows 8. Is it possible to see this through some registry entry or is there any other way to query the value

Answer (score 4):

It is zero, meaning infinity, in every operating system with TCP sockets that I have ever used in over 30 years.

Comment: In Windows 8, while using jdbc, I get the connection reset exception 30 seconds after invoking the request. Hence am not sure if this is set to 0. The exact exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset.

Comment: Classic XY problem. Connection resets have nothing whatsoever to do with `SO_RCVTIMEO`. If you were getting read timeouts you would be getting -1 returned from `read()/recv()/recvfrom()/recvmsg()/readv()` or whatever you were calling, with `errno == EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK`. You are barking up the wrong tree entirely.